# postgres sql: ERROR: syntax error at or near "offset"

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I was using postgres to store data/function.
But there's a confusing problem.

Here's my function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_get_users_page(int4, int4)
   RETURNS SETOF entuser AS
 $BODY$
   DECLARE
      offset ALIAS FOR $1;
      pageSize ALIAS FOR $2;
      select_statement text;
      entuser_row entuser%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;
      select_statement = "SELECT * from entuser order by 'userName' offset " || CAST(offset AS text) || " limit " || CAST(pageSize AS text);
      FOR entuser_row IN EXECUTE select_statement
      LOOP
          RETURN NEXT entuser_row ;
      END LOOP;
   END;
 $BODY$
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
 ALTER FUNCTION sp_get_users_page(int4, int4) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Here's the error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "offset"
LINE 11: ...from entuser order by 'userName' offset " || CAST(offset AS ...

I don't understand where the syntax error is.
I'm looking forward someone could teach me.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should really plan an upgrade as soon as possible. That might also remove the need for the hack using `set enable_seqscan` as the performance and the query optimizer have been improved substantially in the last 8 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String constants need to be enclosed in single quoted, not double quotes. double quotes are for identifiers, e.g.:

```
select_statement := 'select ... order by "userName" offset '||offset||' limit '||pagesize;
```

But your use of a cursor and a loop is unnecessary and makes the query a lot slower than it needs to be. Plus you don't really need dynamic SQL to begin with, you can use variables directly in a static SQL statement.

So the actual function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_get_users_page(p_offset int, p_pagesize int)
   RETURNS SETOF entuser AS
 $BODY$
BEGIN
  SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;
  return query 
     SELECT * 
     FROM entuser 
     ORDER BY "userName" 
     OFFSET p_offset
     LIMIT p_pagesize
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

But you don't really need PL/pgSQL for such a simple function to begin with. A SQL function is typically better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_get_users_page(p_offset int, p_pagesize int)
   RETURNS SETOF entuser AS
 $BODY$
   SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;
   SELECT * 
   FROM entuser 
   ORDER BY "userName" 
   OFFSET p_offset
   LIMIT p_pagesize
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

---

The `SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;` is highly suspicious though - do you really need that?

Comment: Many thanks. It works. You are my idol. In fact, those PGsql scripts wasn't written by me. I'm a new fish in our team so I'm not familiar with the syntax of  PGsql, nor I know the usage of variable ENABLE_SEQSCAN...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why the loop here is useless, could you please tell me more?

Comment: @Joker.Lee: there is no need for a loop because you can return the complete result of a query from within a function without looping over the result